# ember - didLoad event in view for waiting for a ember-data model to load

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

hi i have the following route:

```
MB3.PlaylistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return MB3.Playlist.find(params.playlist_id);
  }
});
```

The playlist has a hasMany realtion with tracks. in the playlist view i want do do some logic with an attribute of the first track of the playlist.

so i added this code:

```
MB3.PlaylistView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.get("controller.tracks").objectAt(0).get("title"));
  }
});
```

The problem is title is undefined (i think because it is not yet loaded. the second thing i tried is waiting for the didLoad event:

```
MB3.PlaylistView = Ember.View.extend({
      didInsertElement: function() {
        var self=this;
        this.get("controller.tracks").on("didLoad", function() {
          console.log(self.get("controller.tracks").objectAt(0).get("title"));
        });
      }
    });
```

but this logges null as well. How do i accomplish that?

Comment: It is probably be because of the issue [#587](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/587). If so, a workaround could be to observe the length of the array.

Comment: hmm this could relate to that bug yes. I also thought about observing the length but then my logic would be executed everytime i add a track aswell. what i want to do is to embed a youtube player to play the songs in the playlist. of course i do only need to embed that player once and change the track via the player api. but i need a video id to embed the player. thats why i wanted the first track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Adrien said in the comments, it seems you are running into [issue 587](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/587). That said, I don't think you actually need the "didLoad" callback in this case. Instead, try using a computed property to get the video_id or track title. For example:

```
MB3.PlaylistView = Ember.View.extend({
  firstTrackTitle: function() {
    return this.get('controller.tracks.firstObject.title');
  }.property('controller.tracks.firstObject.title')      
});
```

Then in your template, embed the player if this property is defined:

```
{{#if view.firstTrackTitle}}
    embed code here
{{/if}}
```

FWIW I would put this logic in controller instead of view, but same idea.

Comment: i'm not quite sure if it is really that bug because if i look at the console in firebug i see that the ajax call is done before any of the console.log calls are printed. thus it should already be there?

Comment: ok i just confirmed that didLoad is called BEFORE the ajax request is done by delaying the request by 5 seconds. it's definitly the bug. In firebug it just prints the get request in the console when it's beginning, not when its'finished.

Comment: about the workaround: this would also be called if i rearrange the tracks in my playlist so that the first track changes. any further ideas?

Comment: From your comment above, sounded like you just needed to make sure that you had a track available to embed the player. For the workaround, the `if` would evaluate to true regardless of track order. Then in your embed code you would use the player api to change tracks, no?

Comment: yes thats right but i want to use swfobject.js to embed the player. so i cannot use an if in the template and would have to use an observer. Which could be called more than one time. I could of course use a variable to save that i already embedded the player but im looking for a clean solution here. but it looks lik i will have to wait for a fix :) Anyway thanks to pointing me to the issue :)

Comment: This method worked for me, except I had to add `return true` to the end of the `firstTrackTitle()` function to get the `{{#if}}` to display.

Comment: @twiz It wasn't working because the value wasn't being returned. If you return the value from this.get instead of returning true the computed becomes even more useful. (returning true is kind of a hack and will return true always, even if no first track exists) I edited the answer to return the value instead of returning nothing, which was a bug.